# Blazor App Server Windows authentication not working after publish

Tags: c#, blazor, windows-authentication

I wanted to create a test application that simply does automatically authorize the user with Windows authentication. Purpose was to test and figure out how basic Windows authentication works, and what I can do with it.

The authentication works when I start the application in Visual Studio 2019. But when I publish the application, and start it locally it does not work anymore. I dont get authenticated anymore.

I created a new Blazor App, Server Side with Authentication method Windows Authentication and overwrote the FetchData.razor page with the following code. I copied this from [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-3.0#blazor-server-side-authentication)

```
@page "/fetchData"
@using System.Security.Claims
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider

<h3>ClaimsPrincipal Data</h3>

<button @onclick="GetClaimsPrincipalData">Get ClaimsPrincipal Data</button>

<p>@_authMessage</p>

@if (_claims.Count() > 0)
{
    <ul>
        @foreach (var claim in _claims)
        {
            <li>@claim.Type: @claim.Value</li>
        }
    </ul>
}

<p>@_surnameMessage</p>

@code {
    private string _authMessage;
    private string _surnameMessage;
    private IEnumerable<Claim> _claims = Enumerable.Empty<Claim>();

    private async Task GetClaimsPrincipalData()
    {
        var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = authState.User;

        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            _authMessage = $"{user.Identity.Name} is authenticated.";
            _claims = user.Claims;
            _surnameMessage =
                $"Surname: {user.FindFirst(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Surname)?.Value}";
        }
        else
        {
            _authMessage = "The user is NOT authenticated.";
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute this on Visual Studio 2019 on my local computer it works perfectly fine. I can press the button, I am authenticated and all my claims get listed aswell.
Then I clean the solution, build again and then publish it without any errors.

I start up the fully published application on my local computer, press the button and it tells me that I am not authenticated. Which I dont understand because the thing that has changed, is that its a published application.

I checked my launchSettings -> windowsAuthentication is True, anonymousAuthentication is False as it should be.

I didnt find anything online and I hope someone knows what causes the problem

Thanks for any help

Comment: You'll also need to [enable windows authentication in IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/#how-to-enable-windows-authentication-for-a-web-site-web-application-or-web-service)

Comment: Dear @DouglasRiddle, I tried enable Windows Authentication in IIS, Also added the lines as mentioned by the Programmer in his response to the query, still facing same issue. Any solution to this issue would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you publish the app to IIS, make sure there's Windows Auth is specified in web.config. For IIS, It would look like:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <authentication>
        <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
      </authentication>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

See MS Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: When trying to set webserver security as above, I am getting following exception message:
This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

Comment: Fixed the error above, by allowing override at machine level, in Machine config. However, still the Windows Authentication is not working for the app.